# XSLT 1.0 Group without using Key

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have been struggling with this problem for hours....help

First I must use XSLT 1.0 and I cannot use xsl:key. I have to sort and group the following xml data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 <?xml-stylesheet href="class2.xsl" type="text/xsl" ?>
 <université>
     <étudiant>
         <nom>Réjean Tremblay</nom>
         <cours sigle="INF8430" note="89" />
         <cours sigle="INF1030" note="69" />
         <cours sigle="INF1230" note="75" />
    </étudiant>
    <étudiant>
         <nom>Martin Lambert</nom>
         <cours sigle="INF8430" note="75" />
         <cours sigle="INF1030" note="72" />
         <cours sigle="INF1230" note="73" />
    </étudiant>
     <étudiant>
         <nom>Luc Alain</nom>
         <cours sigle="INF9430" note="39" />
         <cours sigle="INF1030" note="89" />
         <cours sigle="INF1230" note="79" />
    </étudiant>
     <étudiant>
         <nom>Olive Saint-Amant</nom>
         <cours sigle="INF8430" note="91" />
         <cours sigle="INF1230" note="99" />
    </étudiant>
 </université>
```

The expected result should be

[image]

Comment: "*I cannot use xsl:key.*" Why is that?

Comment: I cannot use the key element to group the courses http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_key.asp

Comment: Are you using XT processor? Otherwise this limitation is ridiculous.

Comment: @user1082748, please explain why you cannot use `xsl:key`.

Comment: Not sure why....it is the client's requirement. I know it is lame

Comment: You might feel obliged to work for a client who tells you to write code with one hand tied behind your back, but most people answering questions here are likely to tell your client to get lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without xsl:key (not optimal, of course)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Sigle</td>
                <td>Nombre d'etuidants</td>
                <td>Moyenne du cours</td>
            </tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="etudiant/cours"/>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="cours[not(@sigle = preceding::cours/@sigle)]">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="@sigle"/>
            </td>
            <xsl:variable name="cnt" select="count(//cours[@sigle = current()/@sigle])"/>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="$cnt"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(//cours[@sigle = current()/@sigle]/@note) div $cnt, '#.0')"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Rudolf! That worked. I wouldn't never have got that. I was so off course.

Comment: It's pretty easy - we have template that matches only those courses that do not have preceding courses with the same identifier. It's not optimal because this check is performed for each course, i.e. we have n^2 complexity.